# How can I show many-to-many junction-tables as part of one of the entities when scaffolding CRUD functionality in ASP.NET MVC EF?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor-pages

I am trying to use EF to scaffold CRUD functionality for a project where I have a entity that has a many-to-many relationship with another entity. This works fine for the most part but I cant figure how I can present the many-to-many relationship data as part of one of the entities.

The scaffolded model of the entity that I want to use looks like this

```
 public partial class Composition
    {
        public Composition()
        {
            CompFish = new HashSet<CompFish>();
        }

        public int CompositionId { get; set; }
        public int AccountId { get; set; }
        public int RodId { get; set; }
        public int ReelId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
        public virtual Reel Reel { get; set; }
        public virtual Rod Rod { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CompFish> CompFish { get; set; }
    }
```

This model has a HashSet of type `CompFish` that is the scaffolded model of the junction-table that hold the relationship between `Composition` and the other entity `Fish` and looks like this

```
public partial class CompFish
    {
        public int CompositionId { get; set; }
        public int FishId { get; set; }

        public virtual Composition Composition { get; set; }
        public virtual Fish Fish { get; set; }
    }
```

So it has an Id from each of the tables it joins and a entity model.

When I want to display the `Fish` part of the `CompFish` attribute in the `HashSet` in my `view` of `Composition` I have done the following;

Modified the controller to include `CompFish`

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var projectFishContext = _context.Composition.Include(c => c.Account).Include(c => c.Reel).Include(c => c.Rod).Include(c => c.CompFish);
            return View(await projectFishContext.ToListAsync());
        }
```

And added a `foreach` loop in the view where I want the data to be displayed.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Account.Mail)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Reel.Brand)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rod.Brand)
            </td>
            <td> // LOOK HERE
                @foreach (var i in item.CompFish)
                {
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => i.Fish.Species)
                }
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.CompositionId">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.CompositionId">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.CompositionId">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
```

The way im using `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => i.Fish.Species)` to display the data may very well be wrong and due to my major brainfarting, I have tried lots of different ways and this is just how it looks currently.. I have been at this for a while and cannot figure out how to do it...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var projectFishContext = _context.Composition.Include(c => c.Account).Include(c => c.Reel).Include(c => c.Rod).Include(c => c.CompFish).ThenInclude(c => c.Fish);
            return View(await projectFishContext.ToListAsync());
        }
```

I missed to add a `ThenInclude` on my collection object